# How to see defined comments on database objects?

Tags: sql, postgresql, descriptor

The main motivation to use [COMMENT ON IS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html), is to generate smart documentation reports,  manipulating it by SQL.

The Guide [postgresql.org/docs/functions-info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) **not explains** (is ugly). I try intuitive `SELECT obj_description('schemaName.tableName'::regclass)` and luckily worked... But I need

1. To do the same with function names, but `name::regclass` not works with functions.
2. To see what is `catalog_name`?  For functions, tables and views.
3. How to easilly (in nowadays 2018) list all the functions or all the tables of a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
so=# create function t.fn() returns int as
$$
begin return 1; end; $$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
so=# comment on function t.fn() is 'some comment';
COMMENT
so=# select * from obj_description('t.fn'::regproc);
 obj_description
-----------------
 some comment
(1 row)
```

`regclass` is for relations, for function use `regproc`

**update**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE

> The two-parameter form of obj_description returns the comment for a
>   database object specified by its OID and the name of the containing
>   system catalog. For example, obj_description(123456,'pg_class') would
>   retrieve the comment for the table with OID 123456. The one-parameter
>   form of obj_description requires only the object OID. It is deprecated
>   since there is no guarantee that OIDs are unique across different
>   system catalogs; therefore, the wrong comment might be returned.

functions oids are stored in `pg_proc`, tables and views in `pg_class` (`relkind` `r` and `v` respectively), thus:

1. `select * from obj_description('t.fn'::regproc)`
2. `pg_class` for tables and views, `pg_proc` for functions
3. below are queries:

for all functions (I add `order` and `limit` to show UDF small list):

```
so=# select oid::regproc,obj_description(oid,tableoid::regclass::text) 
from pg_proc 
order by oid desc 
limit 2;
 oid  | obj_description
------+-----------------
 t.fn | some comment
 a    | blah
(2 rows)
```

for all tables:

```
so=# select oid::regclass,obj_description(oid,tableoid::regclass::text) from pg_class where relkind = 'r' order by oid desc limit 1;
      oid      |   obj_description
---------------+---------------------
 t."WeirdMix$" | table with bad name
(1 row)
```

respectively for views:

```
so=# select oid::regclass,obj_description(oid,tableoid::regclass::text) from pg_class where relkind = 'v' order by oid desc limit 1;
 oid | obj_description
-----+-----------------
 v   | view this is
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks!  you solved the item 1, and was perfect. Can you solve items 2 and 3?  About item 2 the problem is that the Guide say `obj_description(object_oid)` is **deprecated**, so I need to understand `catalog_name` to use non-deprected `obj_description(object_oid, catalog_name)`.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I see where the confusion comes from. And updated the answer